# Objective-C converting to Swift 3.1 getting error 'Any' is not convertible

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsmanagedobject

I'm finally attempting to convert one of my Objective-C apps to Swift 3.1. I'm also taking a tutorial on Swift to help me out. However, I'm running into the following error when trying to convert a 'for in' loop to Swift that worked successfully in Obj-C. I've posted both the Swift and Objective-C code below and commented the line in Swift where I am getting the error. I am getting the error with
 `for managedObject: NSManagedObject in myResults{`

The error states

> 'Any' is not convertible to 'MSManageObject'

Any help pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

```
//IN SWIFT 3.1
            let context: NSManagedObjectContext? = 
CoreDataHelper.shared().context
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: 
"Exhibitors", in: context!)
            fetchRequest.entity = entity
            var myResults : NSArray = try! 
CoreDataHelper.shared().context.fetch(fetchRequest) as NSArray
            self.objects = myResults as! [Any]
            if !(myResults != nil) || !((myResults.count) != nil) {
                print("No Exhibitor objects found to be deleted!")
            }
            else {
        //****Getting error 'Any' is not convertible to 'NSManagedObject'
                for managedObject: NSManagedObject in myResults {
                    if !(managedObject.value(forKey: "fav") == "Yes") {
                        context?.deleteObject(managedObject)
                        var error: Error? = nil
                        // Save the object to persistent store
                        if !context?.save(error) {
                            print("Can't Save! \(error) \
(error?.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                        print("Exhibitor object deleted!")
                    }
                }
            }


//IN OBJECTIVE-C
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[CoreDataHelper sharedHelper] 
context];

                    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] 
init];

                    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
entityForName:@"Exhibitors" inManagedObjectContext:context];

                    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

                    NSArray *myResults = [[[CoreDataHelper sharedHelper] 
context] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
                    self.objects = myResults;
                    if (!myResults || !myResults.count){
                        NSLog(@"No Exhibitor objects found to be deleted!");
                    }
                    else{
                        for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in myResults) {
                            if (![[managedObject valueForKey:@"fav"] 
isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {


                                [context deleteObject:managedObject];


                                NSError *error = nil;
                                // Save the object to persistent store
                                if (![context save:&error]) {
                                    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, 
[error localizedDescription]);
                                }
                                NSLog(@"Exhibitor object deleted!");

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that your are annotating worse types than the compiler infers.

**Don't do that. Don't annotate types unless the compiler tells you to do.**

For example the managed object context is supposed to be non-optional

```
let context = CoreDataHelper.shared().context
```

Your fetch returns `[NSManagedObject]`, never use `NSArray` and never cast distinct types up to more unspecified like `[Any]`

Simply write

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Exhibitors", in: context)
fetchRequest.entity = entity
do {  // its always recommended to do a good error handling !!
   self.objects = try CoreDataHelper.shared().context.fetch(fetchRequest)
   for managedObject in self.objects { 

      ...

   }

} catch { print(error) }
```

If `objects` is empty the loop will be skipped.

Comment: This in addition to @Alistra's recommendation worked after implementing it and accepting what Swift suggested to fix certain issues that cropped up.

Comment: I won't down vote the answer because I'm sure it solved his problem, but the advice to never explicitly annotate a less specific type is not good advice. It is essential programming practice to only expose as much information as is necessary to the context. Often this means deliberately limiting your type knowledge of a certain entity so that the compiler will force you to "color within the lines" so to speak.

Comment: @jeremyabannister That's a good point but my experience here on SO is that in countless questions the questioner messed up the types by annotating them. The human/developer is more error-prone than the compiler. And even Apple recommends in the WWDC talks *let the compiler infer the type*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
var myResults : NSArray = try! CoreDataHelper.shared().context.fetch(fetchRequest) as NSArray
```

Do this:

```
let myResults : [NSManagedObject] = try! CoreDataHelper.shared().context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

You should also use less `!` operators, as they may crash your app, try using the `guard let` pattern or `?` operators.

Comment: With the given fetch request the return type is guaranteed to be `[NSManagedObject]`, the `guard` will never fail.

Comment: Fixed it according to @vadian's comment